# Set Windows font on Linux in SVG with Apache Batik

Tags: java, svg, fonts, batik

I'm developing a simple web application that provides an URL for rendering an SVG image. I use Apache Batik library for SVG rendering and I have a problem with setting `font-family`. I would like the resulting SVG to look identical (as it can) when viewed from any browser (mainly Chrome, FF and Edge) and any OS (mainly Linux and Windows). The problem is, that as I see, Batik uses some internal logic that loads fonts from the local system, and this prevents cross-platform behaviour.

To be more precise: my webapp runs on Ubuntu Linux, and I set `font-family:'DejaVu Sans'` to my graphics. This works perfectly when the client uses Linux, but on Windows, obviously this font does not exist. I tried to set `font-family` according to the `User-Agent` header in the request, but  when I set `font-family:'Verdana'` for Windows clients, Batik tries to load the 'Verdana' font, and it obviously fails.

I tried to set the attribute like this: `font-family:'DejaVu Sans',Verdana` but Batik can not handle comma-separated list of valid font families. Is there any way to resolve this besides installing the Verdana font on the server?

Comment: bundle the actual font, and use a @font-face rule?

Comment: Would this work for an SVG element?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_fonts
Another option may be to embed the font in the SVG, but I think I read somewhere that Batik had problems with that.

Comment: it might very well, yeah. worth giving a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I achieved it by including the font in my app and register it with `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);`. This way Batik properly keeps the `'Verdana'` string in the `font-family` attribute. Thanks for [mike-pomax-kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) for the helpful advice!